# Stream music from file with AudioToolbox

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, audiostreamer

I want to play music from file using AudioToolbox and loop it. I can't use AVFoundation because it is not available on Snow Leopard.

I have downloaded AudioStreamer class and modified it so it plays sound from local file, but I can not loop it.

Help please.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, it supports local file perfectly.

https://github.com/douban/DOUAudioStreamer

Just see example for usage.